# mod_speling & mod_rewrite to work together?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, case-insensitive, mod-speling

```
    CheckSpelling On

    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}                      ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
    RewriteCond     /home/%1/                          -d
    RewriteRule     ^(.+)                              %{HTTP_HOST}$1
    RewriteRule     ^([^.]+)\.example\.com/media/(.*)     /home/$1/data/media/$2
    RewriteRule     ^([^.]+)\.example\.com/(.*)           /home/$1/www/$2
```

The `CheckSpelling On` (mod_speling) works fine when it’s `www.example.com`. But it does not work when the Rewrites take place. For example there is a `/home/test/www/index.html` file. If you do `test.example.com/INDEX.html`     it will not fix to `test.example.com/index.html`  but if you do `www.example.com/INDEX.html` (there is no `/home/www/` folder) it will fix it to `www.example.com/index.html`.

It seems like it processes through the mod_rewrite first and if it uses rewrite, it doesnt go through checkspelling. I have tried loaded the modules in different orders with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

`mod_speling` can't look for spelling alternatives that go through `mod_rewrite` rules.  It should work if you use use a redirect [R], but it looks like you want to hide the actual directories.

You might consider a custom 404 instead of mod_speling.

Comment: Strange. I had a setup that was working 6 months ago, I forgot how or what I did. Since then I have lost 50% of what I had customized ;[

Answer (score 0):

mod_speling and mod_rewrite operate in the same phase when rewrite is used in per-directory context ( or htaccess). This phase runs *all* participating modules, not the first to take any action.

rewrite in per-directory always acts as if it has the [PT] flag. If your rewrites are not in per-directory context, just add the [PT] flag and use URI's instead of filenames in your substitutions will probably get them interoperating.